# Why doesn't Android retrieve the memory usage of widgets after finishing executing?

Tags: android, memory, dialog, garbage-collection, widget

Why doesn't Android retrieve the memory usage of widgets after finishing executing?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The above picture shows as I interact with dialogs.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Dialog builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        builder = new Dialog(this);
        RelativeLayout myrl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Dynamically Coded");
        textview.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                builder.dismiss();
            }
        });
        NumberPicker numpick = new NumberPicker(this);
        numpick.setId(View.generateViewId());
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);
        lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textview.getId());
        lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, numpick.getId());
        myrl.addView(textview, lp);
        myrl.addView(numpick, lp2);
        myrl.addView(edit, lp3);
        builder.setContentView(myrl);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Every time I open the dialog and dismiss the dialog, it takes up about .05MB memory.

Why isn't this 0.05MB memory retrieved right after I dismiss the dialog?

It does garbage collection only when all free memory spaces are being used.

Can somebody please explain why the memory being used is not retrieved right after I dismiss the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't run garbage collector until it has to, because the garbage collection **slows things down** quite a bit and thus shouldn't be run very frequently. It runs when there is **need of** memory to be freed. Thus right after you dismiss the dialog, there is still enough free memory to be used by system (no scarcity yet), so Java doesn't call GC events. It is always preferred to delay GC as much as possible.

If you want to free a process' memory right after it is killed, you can run `System.gc()` but **it is not recommended** to do so.

Comment: Thanks Rohit as always!

Comment: @KyungminLee, Happy to help :)